# Painting a rectangle from an exterior class

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I'm a beginner to Java 2D graphics, currently learning.

I have a class `Surface`, extending `JPanel`, that's overriding `paintComponent` method. It's where the program is supposed to draw things. An instance of `Surface` was added to a different class that extends `JFrame`. This class is called Main, it also included the `main` method.

I'm trying to do that Surface will call a method in the class DrawRect, and that method will create a rectangle in Surface, from the outside.

Here are my attempts:

```
// Class Main

package m;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main m = new Main();

    }

    public Main(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Bla");
        setSize(500,500);
        add(new Surface());
        setVisible(true);

    }

}

// Class Surface

package m;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Surface extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // What to do here?

    }

}

package m;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


// Class DrawRect

public class DrawRect {

    String color;
    Surface surface;

    public DrawRect(String color, Surface surface){
        this.color = color;
        this.surface = surface;
    }

}
```

In other words, how can an exterior class draw something in another class? Thanks

Comment: Show us your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One paint surface is one paint surface. You don't combine then. Even if you were to try and overlap them, you'd still be painting on one surface.

If you want to use a data model for another shape you could do something like this

```
public class MyRetangle{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;
    Color color = Color.RED;

}

public class Surface extends JPanel {
    MyRectangle rect = new MyRectangle();  // create an instance of your other class

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2.setColor(rect.color);      // use data from rect
        g2.draw(new Rectangle.Double(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height));
    }
}
```

This is just an example. I don't know why you would ever do this, but you can see how to use data from another class as drawing data

**Edit:**  to fit more towards your code

```
public class DrawRect{
    int y;
    int y;
    int height;
    int width;
    Color color;

    public DrawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

public class Surface extends JPanel {

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        DrawRect rect = new DrawRect(20, 20, 100, 100, Color.RED);
        g2.setColor(rect.color); 
        g2.draw(new Rectangle.Double(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height));
    }
}
```